# How to run a pipeline for a specific windowStartTime

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Is there an easy way in the portal to re-run a pipeline for a defined window?

Data Factory V1 had the calendar that allowed a slice to be selected and re-ran. What is the equvilent in V2?

I can see the run history page shows all the runs for a window trigger, however you have to open each of the properties pages to find out the parameter value for each run. If I needed to find a specific day to re-run this would be really cumbersome having to open every iten in the to check the value, before re-running the row once I've found it.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Factory support you [Rerun activities inside a pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/monitor-visually#rerun-activities-inside-a-pipeline).

You can get all the pipeline run history in Data Factory monitor.

You can now rerun activities inside a pipeline. Select View activity runs, and then select the activity in your pipeline from which point you want to rerun your pipeline.

[image]

Using filter or Custom Range to find out  which pipeline you want to rerun.

Here's an another document you can reference [Rerun Pipeline activities in Azure Data Factory](https://erwindekreuk.com/2019/03/rerun-pipeline-activities-in-azure-data-factory/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: How do you set the window start parameter using this method?